# Create unique variable based on higher level in which the variable exists

Tags: r

I am encountering the following issue.
My dataset has on each row a different patient, and I have the variables "hospital" and "surgeon", that tell me in which hospital and by which surgeon these patients are operated.

Every surgeon works only in one hospital. There are 20 hospitals and each hospital has somewhere between 3 and 10 surgeons. (around 100 surgeons in total)
The issue is that all surgeons are numbered 1 to 10 in my data. So there is a surgeon 1 in hospital A and a surgeon 1 in hospital B. However, these are different surgeons.

I would like to make a new variable called "surgeon_unique", that has a unique integer (from 0 to 100) for every unique surgeon (based on hospital*surgeon).

Can someone tell me how to do this? I can't find the answer online. Much appreciated!

I hope for something else than a case_when, because I think that would mean that I have to write 100 lines of code (for each combination of hospital + surgeon a new line of code)

Comment: We can easily demonstrate this based on two vectors, but this probably does not match your data (restrictions). Please provide sample data.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use `paste0` as `as.factor` to make a unique surgeon column that is a factor - in R, factors have numbers "hiding" behind them. If you wanted them to be ascribed a number, your could just wrap it in `as.numeric`:

```
df <- data.frame(patient = 1:15,
                 hospital = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5),
                 surgeon = c(rep(1:5, 2), c(2,2,4,5,5)))

df$surgeon_code <- as.factor(paste0(df$hospital, df$surgeon))
df$surgeon_num <- as.numeric(df$surgeon_code)
```

or `dplyr::mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(surgeon_code = as.factor(paste0(hospital, surgeon)),
         surgeon_num = as.numeric(hospital_code))
```

Both output:

```
#    patient hospital surgeon surgeon_code surgeon_num
# 1        1        A       1           A1           1
# 2        2        A       2           A2           2
# 3        3        A       3           A3           3
# 4        4        A       4           A4           4
# 5        5        A       5           A5           5
# 6        6        B       1           B1           6
# 7        7        B       2           B2           7
# 8        8        B       3           B3           8
# 9        9        B       4           B4           9
# 10      10        B       5           B5          10
# 11      11        C       2           C2          11
# 12      12        C       2           C2          11
# 13      13        C       4           C4          12
# 14      14        C       5           C5          13
# 15      15        C       5           C5          13
```

Comment: Hi jpsmith. This was the answer I was hoping for, very easy solution! Thank you very much

Comment: @FlorisB. great! If this answers the question and no better answers come up, consider clicking the checkmark by the answer to mark it as answered. This will let others know it’s sufficiently answered and helps clean up the site!